# Use recursion to prove the bounds of the Fibonacci numbers when $n\geq 2$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, fibonacci-numbers, upper-lower-bounds, python

**Use recursion** and the following function fib (for the computation of a Fibonacchi number):

```
def fib(n):
  if n <2:
    return 1
  else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

To prove that $2^n\geq F_n\geq 2^\frac{n}{2}$ when $n\geq 2$ and $n$ is an integer.

The key here is that I'm supposed to "use recursion" to accomplish this proof.  However, I'm confused by this and am uncertain as to how I should be using recursion to prove that those values are bounds for the Fibonacci numbers when $n\geq 2$.  How would I do this?  Thank you.

Comment: use proof by induction - it is definitely true for $n=2$ , prove that if it is true for $n=k$ it must also be true for $n=k+1$

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion means that you need to use the recursive definition of $F_n$, that is the given code. The proof itself is just a variant of strong induction: you need to prove two base cases, because the next $k$-inequality uses the previous two inequalities.

This is easy to see for $n=2$ and $n=3$.

Suppose the inequalities are true for all $2\leq k \leq n+1$.
Then use that $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$ and sum the two inequalities $2^{n+1}\geq F_{n+1}\geq 2^\frac{n+1}{2}$ and $2^n\geq F_n\geq 2^\frac{n}{2}$ to obtain
$$2^{n+2}=4\cdot 2^n\geq3\cdot 2^n =2^n+2^{n+1}\geq F_{n+2}\geq 2^\frac{n}{2}+2^\frac{n+1}{2}=(1+\sqrt{2})2^\frac{n}{2}\geq 2\cdot 2^\frac{n}{2}= 2^\frac{n+2}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use induction...

$n=2$:   $2^2\ge2\ge2^{\frac 22}$

Assume true for $k\le n$..

$n+1$: $ F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ 
So $$2^{n+1}\gt3(2^{n-1})=2^n+2^{n-1}\ge F_{n+1}\ge2^{\frac n2}+2^{\frac {n-1}2}=2^{\frac {n-1}2}(2^{\frac12}+1).\ge2^{\frac {n-1}2}\cdot2=2^{\frac {n+1}2}$$........

Answer (score 0):

Lower bound.

Suppose
$F_n > a^n$
and
$F_{n+1} > a^{n+1}$.
We want to see
what condition on $a$
will imply
$F_{n+2} > a^{n+2}$.

$F_{n+2}
=F_{n+1}+F_n
\gt a^{n+1}+a^n
=a^n(a+1)
$.
This is
$\gt a^{n+2}$
if
$a^n(a+1) > a^{n+2}$
or
$a+1 > a^2
$
or
$\frac54 > a^2-a+\frac14
=(a-\frac12)^2
$
or
$a 
< \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac12
\approx 1.618
$.

Since $\sqrt{2}
\approx 1.414
\lt 1.618$,
using
$a = \sqrt{2}$
and
$(\sqrt{2})^n
=2^{n/2}
$
gives the lower bound
once we have shown it
for two consecutive $F_n$.

This is almost
exactly the same for
the upper bound.

Suppose
$F_n < a^n$
and
$F_{n+1} < a^{n+1}$.
We want to see
what condition on $a$
will imply
$F_{n+2} < a^{n+2}$.

Doing exectly the same analysis,
we find that
the condition is
$a 
> \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac12
\approx 1.618
$.

Since $2 > 1.618$,
this gives the upper bound.

All that is left
is to show that
the bounds hold
for two consecutive $F_n$.

To analytically show
the inequalities:

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{2} < \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac12\\
\iff 2\sqrt{2} < \sqrt{5}+1\\
\iff 8 < (\sqrt{5}+1)^2 =6+2\sqrt{5}\\
\iff 1 < \sqrt{5}\\
\text{which is true.}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
2 > \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac12\\
\iff 3 > \sqrt{5}\\
\iff 9 > 5\\
\text{which is true.}\\
\end{array}
$